# type str doesn't define __round__ method/how to grab form fields ? django and cropper.js?

Tags: python, django, image, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django form where users would upload images and sometimes crop only parts from it so I used cropper javascript to grab the coordinates but the problem is the data received is treated as strings

here's how i grab data of the form

```
  /* SCRIPT TO COLLECT THE DATA AND POST TO THE SERVER */
  $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
    var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
    $("#id_x").val(cropData["x"]);
    $("#id_y").val(cropData["y"]);
    $("#id_height").val(cropData["height"]);
    $("#id_width").val(cropData["width"]);
    $("#formUpload").submit();
  });
```

## Forms.py

```
class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    width = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = UploadedImages
        fields = ('pre_analysed', 'x', 'y', 'width', 'height', )
```

and this is how i get the data from the form

```
if form.is_valid():
   image = form.save(commit=False)
   x = request.POST.get('x')
   y = request.POST.get('y')
   w = request.POST.get('width')
   h = request.POST.get('height')
```

but it always returns this error

> type str doesn't define **round** method

so what i get is that I'm grabbing the data as strings instead of floats as it's saved in the form feild so how can i grab the data right ?

Comment: _I'm grabbing the data as strings instead of floats as it's saved in the form feild_ If you had initialized an `ImageForm` from the post data and fetched the fields from there, I believe they would be native floats.  But you didn't; you got the fields from the raw post data, where they are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[DjangoProject.Docs]: Request and response objects - QueryDict objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) (which `HttpRequest.POST` is), the request attributes are stored as strings. 
You should convert them to floating point numbers:

```py
x = float(request.POST.get('x'))
y = float(request.POST.get('y'))
w = float(request.POST.get('width'))
h = float(request.POST.get('height'))
```

Comment: Thanks that did work and now I get the values as floats(tried to print them) but the image isn't cropped yet.

Comment: You're welcome! Hmm, unfortunately that is waaay beyond my *Django* knowledge. But if you don't figure it out in the mean time, that could be the subject of another question :)